# dependency to pointcloud-to-laserscan

Tags: ros-noetic

When I try to install dependencies on `ros-noetic` using `rosdep`:

```sh
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot locate rosdep definition for [pointcloud-to-laserscan]
```

I already have that dependency listed on my `package.xml` file:

```xml
<exec_depend>pointcloud-to-laserscan</exec_depend>
```

[link to pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan)

Can you tell me how can I solve that please? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong name. The correct string is "pointcloud_to_laserscan".

You can list all the known rosdep names with the command `rosdep db`.